# Node.js: Push File Names into an Array in an Async-Await Way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I would like to get some help because I just can not figure out how to use an async-await methods recursively in Node.js.

I am trying to create a function that returns all the files in all subfolders as an array using the file-system module.

I did saw a lot of examples online, but none of these used an array and than waited for an answer.

Thanks!

```js
 function checkFiles () {
 
   const files = []
   const getFiles = async dir =>  fs.readdir(`./${dir}`, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, inners) => {
      if (err) {
         throw new Error (err)
      }
      else {
         inners.forEach(inner => {
            inner.isDirectory() ? getFiles(`${dir}/${inner.name}`) : files.push(`file: ${inner.name}`);
         });
      };
   });
   getFiles('.')
   if (files.length === 0) {
      return 'no files'
   }
   else {
      return files
   }
   
 }
 
 console.log(checkFiles())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `getFiles` asynchronously, and within `getFiles` you pass a callback to `readdir` instead of `await`ing it.
What you should try is adding `await` to both lines:

```js
function checkFiles() {
    const files = []
    const getFiles = async dir => {
        try {
            inners = await fs.readdir(`./${dir}`, { withFileTypes: true })
            inners.forEach(inner => {
                inner.isDirectory() ? getFiles(`${dir}/${inner.name}`) : files.push(`file: ${inner.name}`);
                });
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
    };
    await getFiles('.')
    
    if (files.length === 0) {
        return 'no files'
    }
    return files
}
```

This will cause the program to halt when reaching `getFiles()`, and continue the execution only after it has finished, meaning `files` is ready for usage.

Comment: Unfortunately that still didn't work. I try to run your code a few times, but the awaiting didn't happened and always got 'no files'.